# Optimization of itertools for billion combinations

Tags: combinations, python-itertools

I deal with the generation of billion combinations using the itertools module in python.  For example, I have
`A=[[0.0, 963.07438, 1926.14876], [0.0, 3203.76339, 6407.52678], [0.0, 3231.67715, 6463.3543]]`.

I need to generate a lot of combinations of A in a way: each element from sub-nest. For example, here
`k=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 3231.67715), (0.0, 0.0, 6463.3543), (0.0, 3203.76339, 0.0), (0.0, 3203.76339, 3231.67715), (0.0, 3203.76339, 6463.3543), (0.0, 6407.52678, 0.0), (0.0, 6407.52678, 3231.67715), (0.0, 6407.52678, 6463.3543), (963.07438, 0.0, 0.0), (963.07438, 0.0, 3231.67715), (963.07438, 0.0, 6463.3543), (963.07438, 3203.76339, 0.0), (963.07438, 3203.76339, 3231.67715), (963.07438, 3203.76339, 6463.3543), (963.07438, 6407.52678, 0.0), (963.07438, 6407.52678, 3231.67715), (963.07438, 6407.52678, 6463.3543), (1926.14876, 0.0, 0.0), (1926.14876, 0.0, 3231.67715), (1926.14876, 0.0, 6463.3543), (1926.14876, 3203.76339, 0.0), (1926.14876, 3203.76339, 3231.67715), (1926.14876, 3203.76339, 6463.3543), (1926.14876, 6407.52678, 0.0), (1926.14876, 6407.52678, 3231.67715), (1926.14876, 6407.52678, 6463.3543)`

Thus, I have N^k combination, here N=3,k=3 ->27.

I can do it using

`sums = ((vs,sum(vs)) for vs in itertools.product(*A))`

But, I need to reduce this k with saving only the combinations with the specific conditions: abs(v-12000)<(2000).
For, example here, I have only 6 combinations:
`(0.0, 6407.52678, 6463.3543), (963.07438, 3203.76339, 6463.3543), (963.07438, 6407.52678, 3231.67715), (963.07438, 6407.52678, 6463.3543), (1926.14876, 3203.76339, 6463.3543), (1926.14876, 6407.52678, 3231.67715)` satisfying this condition.

Finally, I have this code:

```
sums = ((vs,sum(vs)) for vs in itertools.product(*A))

for k,v in sums:
    
    if (abs(v-12000)<(2000)):
        print k
```

It takes a lot of time, when I have N=108 and k=10 (billion combinations).

How can I speed up or optimize this code? Maybe there is alternative to itertools?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a task for dynamic programming; you can build a table using the recurrence formula:

```py
combs[i, t] = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    ((*c, j) for c in combs[i-1, t-v])
    for j,v in enumerate(A[i-1])
))
```

to build a table; where `combs[i,t]` is the list of tuples of length `i` using one element from each of the `i` first sublists of `A`, such that these elements sum to `t` (plus or minus your tolerance `tol=2000`).

You can initalise the edges of the table:

```py
combs[0, t] = [()] if t <= tol
combs[0, t] = [] if t > tol
combs[i, t] = [] if t + tol < 0
combs[i, t] = [] if t - tol > i * max_element_of_A # this can be refined further using itertools.accumulate on the list of maximums of the lists of A
```

The table will have:

- one row for each possible value of `i` (between 0 and k);
- one column for each possible value of `t` (between 0 and 12000, but you can round all elements in `A` to units or tens or hundreds to decrease the number of possible values)